# Dual boot for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and Windows 8.1

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, grub2, windows-8

I have Windows 8.1 **Lenovo S510P** laptop on which I installed **Ubuntu 14.04 LTS**.

But not able do boot repair, [or] edit grub; so when I power on laptop I should get option to go Windows or Ubuntu.

Right now I can only able to login to **Ubuntu**.

Comment: Check the output from: **`sudo update-grub`** *Is there still a Windows 8.1 partition found?*

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to update grub, which can be done by running sudo update-grub. This usually is caused by grub failing to recognize Windows 8.1. Worse case senario you might have to reinstall grub entirely. To do that, see this link;

http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd